# Why there are some many ways to create Strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, programming-languages

I already seen this one [Why are there so many slightly different ways to do the same thing in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1797112/104337) but it doesn't help a bit. Having multiple slightly different semantics and syntax for the same thing is IMHO confusing and counterproductive. I was trying to find some spec, or rationale on why this is so, but they're nowhere to be found (unlike Java and Python where every language feature is well documented with motivation etc.).

It's not just String, it's everything. What I'm looking for is a generic explanation on why the japanese think that having 100 ways to do the same thing is better than one explicit way. Remember that we're talking about programming language, that's not a musical instrument, or a paint brush, it's a tool to get the job done and have fun along the way. It's not fun to read some code and wonder why she used `%<hello kitty>` instead of `"hello kitty"`, especially when you're looking for a bug.

I see the benefit in standardization, which is a related concept. I hope everyone else does. Why doesn't Ruby support some 100 versions of customized HTTP protocol, for the same reason they support 100 ways to create a String?

Comment: Don't worry, it's not Perl ;-) Anyway, "that's just how the language is". The Mailing Lists are more appropriate for this question, perhaps, but it is OT here because there is no other "definitive" answer than the one I gave.

Answer (score 3):

The reason there's many different ways to create a string is because there's many reasons you might need a string. Since strings are the backbone of many applications, it makes sense that this facility is robust and varied.

Once you're used to it, you'll find the rigid quotation systems in other languages to be more of a nuisance than anything. HTML often requires using both single `'` and double `"` quotes for embedded JavaScript or other attributes, and unless you want to render your string into unreadable pulp by spiking in backslashes `\` before any of them you'll be better off with the `%q[ ... ]` type method of quoting.

Any good toolbox has a variety of tools. Don't complain that your wrench set is confusing because it has so many different sizes of wrench. Sometimes you'll need a specific one, and then you'll be grateful. Many of these methods have been borrowed from languages like Perl, and Perl is inspired by other things like bash.

Typical use cases:

```
double_quotes = "typical use case with #{variables}"
single_quotes = 'strict string literals'
alternate_double_quotes = %Q[<for html="tags('with both quotes', 'and #{variables}')">]
alternate_single_quotes = %q[<for html="tags('with both quotes')">]
inline_string = <<END
Useful for long blocks of freeform
text such as sample data or templates.
END
```

I've found that the `%q[ ... ]` method comes in handy when trying to express multi-line strings that contain quotes as is often the case with SQL:

```
execute(%q[
  INSERT INTO examples (id, feature_code)
    SELECT id, CONCAT('example_', feature_code)
      FROM things
      GROUP BY foo
      ORDER BY bar
])
```

It is relatively easy to spot `[ ... ]` pairings but not as easy when you have many escaped quotes. It's easy to miss a closing quote unless you have a syntax highlighting editor.